# Multiple queries mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I'm trying to input multiple queries guys using mysqli. Yet it's not populating the database. Any ideas?

```
$q2="UPDATE ticketinfo SET ticketstatus = $status where ticketno = $ticket; 
  insert into ticketinfo (remarks) values ('$remarks')";

$ex2= mysqli_multi_query($conn,$q2);
```

Comment: Check for syntax errors.

Comment: I did bro. But it seems it's not getting to these part. 

if ($ex2){
    echo 'We have successfully processed your ticket update. Thank you.>'; 
}


else {
  echo 'We have received an error while processing your ticket update. Please try again.';
  mysqli_error ($conn);
}

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries should be executed sequentially. **Never use `mysqli_multi_query()` with variable input.** You should be using parameterized prepared statements. There is hardly any use case for `mysqli_multi_query()` at all.

Your code should look like this:

```
// your mysqli connection
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

// First query
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE ticketinfo SET ticketstatus = ? WHERE ticketno = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $status, $ticket);
$stmt->execute();

// Second query
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO ticketinfo (remarks) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $remarks);
$stmt->execute();
```

I used two prepared statements and bound the input separately. This much better, cleaner and safer option than `mysqli_multi_query()`.